# How to Download IBM Cloud Bucket data into loacl directory using ibm-cos-sdk python library

Tags: python, amazon-s3, websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I am Working on ibm cloud object storage using python, i have used ibm-cos-sdk library to establish connection and doing the following operations

```
-> Creating Bucket
-> List Created Buckets
-> Uploading data init

But i am unable to download contents form the bucket

s3.download_file(Filename=filename, Bucket=bucket, Key=objectname)


I am uisng download_file function, getting client error

I am new to ibm cloud.
```

Comment: what's the error message or the return code?

Comment: i am getting "NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"  error

Comment: `import ibm_boto3
from ibm_botocore.client import Config

api_key = 'xxxxxxx'
service_instance_id = 'xxxxxxx'
auth_endpoint = 'https://iam.bluemix.net/oidc/token'
service_endpoint = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net'


cos = ibm_boto3.resource('s3',
ibm_api_key_id=api_key,
ibm_service_instance_id=service_instance_id,
ibm_auth_endpoint=auth_endpoint,
config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
endpoint_url=service_endpoint)

s3 = ibm_boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file('lkjh', 'sample.csv', '/tmp/sample.csv')`

Comment: **i am using this code for download data in the bucket**